# how to get CI config set variable value?

Tags: codeigniter

how to get CI config set variable value?

```
I am working in CI. I have require base url in Controller file.

I am use base_url(); function but show error.
```

Comment: require 'config.php';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constants for base url for eg.define('BASE_URL','http://domain.com') in constant.php

Answer (score 1):

have you load the helper of url??
Go to (your project)->Source Files->application->config->autoload.php
then find

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

and load url like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```